# Removing artifacts from my plot that draws Homer Simpson

Tags: plotting

I'm doing "[Drawing Homer with Epicycles](http://www.qedcat.com/misc/homer1.pdf)" (from the video: [Epicycles, complex Fourier series and Homer Simpson's orbit](https://youtu.be/qS4H6PEcCCA) by 
Mathologer)

It uses `FindShortestTour` to make the drawing close to shortest roundtrip. However, using `FindShortestTour` introduces a change from the original (especially a vertical line in right eye of Homer)
[image: Homer]

I don't want the drawing to be changed. What else can I use instead `FindShortestTour`? Alternatively, how can I keep it from changing though using `FindShortestTour`?